# ¿Cómo evitar que HEREDOC remplace todo el archivo?

Tags: php

Ando usando HEREDOC <<< para escribir unas líneas en un archivo .txt, el problema es que reemplaza todo el texto y eso no lo quiero, en vez de eso que sólo se añada dichas líneas al archivo de texto al comienzo. ¿Alguien tiene algún método o solución?, les doy las gracias por todo.

```
$str = <<<EOD

primera línea ejemplo


segunda línea ejemplo

EOD;

$archivo = fopen("../prueba.txt", "w");
fwrite($archivo, PHP_EOL .$str);
fclose($archivo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es HEREDOC el problema. Es el modo de escritura debes elegir uno de estos dos:

```
$archivo = fopen("../prueba.txt", "a");
```

Abre el archivo para sólo escritura. La escritura comenzará al final del archivo, sin afectar al contenido previo. Si el fichero no existe se intenta crear.

```
$archivo = fopen("../prueba.txt", "a+");
```

Abre el archivo para lectura y escritura. La lectura o escritura comenzará al final del fichero, sin afectar al contenido previo. Si el fichero no existe se intenta crear.

ya que W lo sobreescribe

```
 $archivo = fopen("../prueba.txt", "W");
```

Abre el archivo sólo para escritura. La escritura comienza al inicio del archivo, y elimina el contenido previo. Si el archivo no existe, intenta crearlo.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte amigo, pensaba que HEREDOC era el problema. Cualquier inconveniente te lo comento.

Comment: Haz pruebas solo con un $str = ''Algo de texto" primero,  y si te resulta , vas a ver que funciona con $str = <<<EOD ... EOD;